# Trouble installing LLVM 10 (liblldb-10)

Tags: llvm, deb

Trying to install LLVM 10 and unable to on deb based machine. When I try to run `sudo apt-get install -f llvm-10 lldb-10 llvm-10-dev libllvm10 llvm-10-runtime`

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
llvm-10 is already the newest version (1:10.0.1~++20211003084855+ef32c611aa21-1~exp1~20211003085243.2).
llvm-10-dev is already the newest version (1:10.0.1~++20211003084855+ef32c611aa21-1~exp1~20211003085243.2).
llvm-10-dev set to manually installed.
libllvm10 is already the newest version (1:10.0.1~++20211003084855+ef32c611aa21-1~exp1~20211003085243.2).
libllvm10 set to manually installed.
llvm-10-runtime is already the newest version (1:10.0.1~++20211003084855+ef32c611aa21-1~exp1~20211003085243.2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblldb-10 : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Have been trying to resolve this for hours but nothing works including this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061762/ubuntu-18-04-cant-upgrade-because-of-libpython3-6-version-conflicts)